# How to initialize a 2D array of strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, initialization

I know how to declare the array and I have done so:

```
String[][] board1 = new String[10][10];
```

Now I want to make it so that every space is "-" by default (without the quotes of course). I have seen other questions like this but the answers didn't make sense to me. All I can understand is that I would probably need a for loop.

Answer (score 9):

The quickest way I can think of is to use [`Arrays.fill(Object[], Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) like so,

```
String[][] board1 = new String[10][10];
for (String[] row : board1) {
    Arrays.fill(row, "-");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board1));
```

This is using a [`For-Each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate the `String[]`(s) of `board1` and fill them with a "-". It then uses [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) to print it.

Answer (score 5):

You could do ...

```
String[][] board1 = new String[][] {
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
};
```

or

```
String[][] board1 = new String[10][10];
for (int outter = 0; outter < board1.length; outter++) {
    String[] row = new String[board1[outter].length];
    for (int inner = 0; inner < row.length; inner++) {
        row[inner] = "-";
    }
    board1[outter] = row;
}
```

or

```
String[][] board1 = new String[10][10];
for (int outter = 0; outter < board1.length; outter++) {
    for (int inner = 0; inner < board1[outter].length; inner++) {
        board1[outter][inner] = "-";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I really wonder why the `first method` **cannot** specify the **size**. Really **CANNOT**, why? `new long[2][2] { {1, 1}, {1, 0}};` will fail.

Comment: @Hearen Really never though out it, but I think the language is just basically saying you either tell me up front or you show me

Comment: It kind of makes sense but still is weird if both provided, it will turn out to be an *error*.