# how to create multi dimensional array dynamic in java?

Tags: java, android

I have my array which is static, now i want to make it dynamic using for loop

```
int[][] args = new int[][]{{6815, 11524},{6845, 11567},{6815, 11524}};
```

I want add value using for loop, how can i do it

I tried but don't get complete, like

```
for(int k=0;k<5;k++){
  // here i can add both both value {6815, 11524} as int.
}
```

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Define what you mean by static/dynamic. Those two words are not mutually exclusive, you may mean something else.

Comment: you should work through some java tutorials

Comment: Where do you want to add it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a 2D array of strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351251/how-to-initialize-a-2d-array-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you want to do is this:

```
// Create a 2D array of length of 5
int[][] args = new int[5][];
// Iterate from 0 to 4
for(int k=0;k<5;k++){
    // Affect the value of the array for the index k
    args[k] = new int[]{6815, 11524};
}
```

**NB:** If you don't know the size of your array, consider using a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead. The code will then be something like that:

```
List<int[]> args = new ArrayList<>();
...
args.add(new int[]{6815, 11524});
```